# Appengine entity update not working

Tags: google-app-engine, sql-update

I am developing code for app engine. I tried to update an existing row by updating the same entity returned as result of query. But it creates new row instead of updating the same row. Following is the code:

```
public boolean updateProfile(DbProfile profile) {

Transaction txn = _datastore.beginTransaction();
Entity entity = getProfileEntity(profile.getLoginId());
if (entity != null) {
    entity.setProperty(DbProfile.DbProfilePropertyNames.address, profile.getAddress());
    entity.setProperty(DbProfile.DbProfilePropertyNames.name, profile.getName());
    Key key = _datastore.put(entity);
    txn.commit();
    return true;
}
return false;
}

private Entity getProfileEntity(String userName) {

Key eRecommendationKey = KeyFactory.createKey("eRecommendation", _dbKeyName);
FilterPredicate predicateUsername =
    new FilterPredicate(DbProfile.DbProfilePropertyNames.loginId, FilterOperator.EQUAL,
                userName.toUpperCase());
Query query =
    new Query(DbProfile.entityProfileName, eRecommendationKey).setFilter(predicateUsername);
List<Entity> profiles =
        _datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
Utils.log.log( Level.SEVERE, "not found"+profiles.size() );
if (profiles.size() == 0) {
    //profile data is not set yet
    return null;
} else {
    return profiles.get(0);
}
}
```

Following image shows fields in the entity.
[image]

Please let me know how can I fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was my mistake. I had called saveData servlet instead of updateProfile servlet.

Answer (score 0):

My Java skills are not too good, so I find it difficult to understand your code sample. I also don't see where `updateProfile()` is called and how your code is getting or constructing the profile object, especially whether the key of the profile object is altered.

But in general, if new entities are created instead of updating existing entities, the reason is that the key at your updating commit is different from the actual key of the existing entity.

Typical situations:

- a string (key-name) is used instead of an integer (ID), or vice versa
- a typo in the kind name of the key
- different namespace or app properties of the key
- parents are missing in the key path or are constructed wrongly

Suggestion:

In datastore viewer, compare the key of an existing entity with the key of the accidentally created entity. The difference between both keys might give you a hint where to look in your code for the bug.